# Python webscraping cannot accest span elements

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the data from the following link
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1652707/000165270718000002/xslFormDX01/primary_doc.xml

I want to find the industry group based on the checkbox but was not able to access the span element from the following code

```
<td><table border="0" summary="Table with single CheckBox"><tr>
<td class="CheckBox"><span class="FormData">X</span></td>
<td align="left" class="FormText">Other Health Care</td>
</tr></table></td>
```

Here is what I have tried

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
#specifying the url of the page
browser.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1753852/000175385218000001/xslFormDX01/primary_doc.xml')
#specifying the url of the page
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table',{'summary':'Issuer Identity Information'})
td = table.find_all('td',{'class':'FormData'})
industry = soup.find('table',{'summary':'Industry Group'})
industrylist = industry.find_all('table',{'summary':'Table with single CheckBox'})
spanelement = industrylist[10]
print(spanelement)
```

And the result has no span element within it, which i wanted to access to find the industry

```
<table border="0" summary="Table with single CheckBox"><tbody><tr>
<td class="CheckBox">  </td>
<td align="left" class="FormText">Other Health Care</td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

I am new to web scraping, could someone please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not perfect but very close. Try the below script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1753852/000175385218000001/xslFormDX01/primary_doc.xml"

res = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for items in soup.select("table[summary='Industry Group'] .CheckBox"):
    if "X" in items.text:
        industry = items.find_parent().select_one(".FormText").text
        print(industry)
```

Output:

```
Pooled Investment Fund
Other Investment Fund
Yes
```